# Docker image not found when running docker push to ECR

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm, elastic-container-registry

I have this working in development (because everything is on one machine), but on production I have a docker swarm with managers and worker nodes. When I run `docker commit` it creates a snapshot and running `docker image ls` confirms this, but when I try to push to a private registry (ecr) docker cannot find the image. I guess this is because the image is on the worker and the manager cannot find it, or the image is on the manager and the worker cannot find it. How can I fix this?

```
{ 
  Error: '(HTTP code 404) no such image - No such image: {account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{repo}:{tag}'
    at /root/labs/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:257:17
    at getCause (/root/labs/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:287:7)
    at Modem.buildPayload (/root/labs/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:256:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/root/labs/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:232:14)
    at Object.apply (/root/labs/node_modules/harmony-reflect/reflect.js:2064:37)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Object.apply (/root/labs/node_modules/harmony-reflect/reflect.js:2064:37)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at Object.apply (/root/labs/node_modules/harmony-reflect/reflect.js:2064:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  reason: 'no such image',
  statusCode: 404,
  json: { 
    message: 'No such image: {account-id}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{repo}:{tag}' 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by logging into the worker that ran the container. Running docker container commit saves a snapshot of the image in the local repo, which is located on the node the container is running on. If that node is on another host, which was my case, running docker push image will not work because the manager will not have access to the workers local repo. So just connect to the worker directly and run docker push image.